# IHtmlHelper in ASP.NET CORE 3.0 - what is the proper way of getting property value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

There were tons of useful helpers in `MVC` for working with `HtmlHelper`s. Now all of them are gone and I am trying to migrate one of my apps into `CORE 3.0`.

I have a helper with the following signature:

```
public static IHtmlContent BootstrapDropDownFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
    List<SelectListItem> selectListItems, 
    object htmlAttributes)
{
```

I would like to know what is the proper way of getting the property value/name from the expression itself.

As a workaround I am using this:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>(
    this TSource source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expr)
{
    var type = typeof(TSource);
    if (!(expr.Body is MemberExpression member))
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{expr}' refers to a method, not a property.");
    var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{expr}' refers to a field, not a property.");
    if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType && propInfo.ReflectedType != null && !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{expr}' refers to a property that is not from type {type}.");
    return propInfo;
}

public static TProperty GetProperty<TSource, TProperty>(
    this TSource source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expr)
{
    return (TProperty) source.GetPropertyInfo(expr).GetValue(source);
}

public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TProperty>(
    this TSource source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expr)
{
    return source.GetPropertyInfo(expr).Name;
}
```

:

```
var exprPropName = model.GetPropertyName(expression);

var exprProp = model.GetProperty(expression)
```

I just want to know what is the replacement for the missing logic (possibly linked to ModelExplorer/metadata, if any)?

Comment: Tag helpers replace html helpers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I have no idea how this is answering my question but thanks for the input nevertheless.